# Code doesn't send a mail with an attachment

Tags: android, api, email, attachment

I am trying to send an email with an attachment file in Android. If I'm sending only message it comes to my mail, but if I want also send attachment with it, it doesn't come on my mail.

What is the reason?

If you want I may send You all my code.

```
 public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

     //Declaring Variables
     private Context context;
     private Session session;

     //Information to send email
     private String email;
     private String subject;
     private String message;
     private String filePath;

     //Progressdialog to show while sending email
     private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

     //Class Constructor
     public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message, String filePath){
         //Initializing variables
         this.context = context;
         this.email = email;
         this.subject = subject;
         this.message = message;
         this.filePath = filePath;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         //Showing progress dialog while sending email
         progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Saadan KT","See võib aega võtta",false,false);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
         super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
         //Dismissing the progress dialog
         progressDialog.dismiss();
         //Showing a success message
         Toast.makeText(context,"Korras;)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         //Creating properties
         Properties props = new Properties();

         //Configuring properties for gmail
         //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
         props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
         props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
         props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
         props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
         props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

         //Creating a new session
         session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                 new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                     //Authenticating the password
                     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                         return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                     }
                 });

         try {
             //Creating MimeMessage object
             MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

             //Setting sender address
             mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
             //Adding receiver
             mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
             //Adding subject
             mm.setSubject(subject);
             //Adding message
             //mm.setText(message);

             MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
             BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
             messageBodyPart.setText(message);
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
             MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
             DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(filePath);
             messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));

             // add image to the multipart
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

             // put everything together
             mm.setContent(multipart);



             //Sending email
             Transport.send(mm);

         } catch (MessagingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I see no attachment code.

Comment: `messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));` you forgot a 2?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the attachment code. 
May be this might help you . Have a look.

First of all add the handler for multipart/ mixed part.

```
// There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
// handler for multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
```

Now add the attachment part.,

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setText(message);
multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

//setup attachments
ArrayList<String> attachmentsPath = new ArrayList<String>();

//setup attachments
File file = new File(filepath);
MimeBodyPart attachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
attachBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
String name = file.getName();
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "attaching file " + name);
attachBodyPart.setFileName(name);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachBodyPart);
attachmentsPath.add(file.getAbsolutePath());

// Put parts in message
mm.setContent(multipart);

//Sending email
Transport.send(mm);
```

Comment: Then please check the file you are adding, is file-path correct. Because it's working code, I have used it in several projects and running fine. Can you please any log activities?